# Error: unexpected '}' in " }" in loop within a loop (while function)

Tags: r, loops, while-loop

This is my code on R, and it keeps getting me the message

> Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"

when I try to run it. What is the problem? I checked the balance of the brackets and according to forums it should work.

```
n = 1 
while(n < 3) { 
    i = 2
    while (i < 17) {
        data_freq = data_pourcentage %>%
            filter(groupe = i & groupe = n) %>%
            mutate(pourcentage = sum(freq)) %>%
            mutate(pourcentage = freq / pourcentage)
        data_pourcentage = left_join(
            data_freq, 
            data_pourcentage, 
            by = c(
                "sujet", "groupe", "identification", 
                "cristallisation", "valence", "freq")
            )
        i = i + 1
    }
    n = n + 1
}
```

Comment: Can you give some sample data so we can actually run it?

Comment: The `&` in the `filter` command is the problem. Just with `filter(groupe = i)` all works fine. Do you mean `filter(groupe= c(i,n))`?

Comment: awesome that was the problem! you rock mate :D

Comment: I would also try and replace the nested `while` loop with a call to `group_by`.

Answer (score 1):

The `&` in the filter command is the problem. Just with `filter(groupe = i)` all works fine. To combine more components use `filter(groupe= c(i,n))`.

```
n = 1 
while(n < 3) { 
    i = 2
    while (i < 17) {
        data_freq = data_pourcentage %>%
            filter(groupe = c(i,n)) %>%
            mutate(pourcentage = sum(freq)) %>%
            mutate(pourcentage = freq / pourcentage)
        data_pourcentage = left_join(
            data_freq, 
            data_pourcentage, 
            by = c("sujet", "groupe", "identification", 
                   "cristallisation", "valence", "freq")
            )
        i = i + 1
    }
    n = n + 1
}
```